# Set text of textbox on button click

Tags: python, qt

I have the code of a cipher and designed a GUI for it in PyQt and am now attempting to integrate the two now but I have become stuck.

I want to be able to push the Generate Key button which will then run the generatekey function I have and display it in the text box to the left of the button. I tried with .setText() but could not get it to work. The object name for the text box is *keytext*. Not really sure what to do, when I push the button now it just crashes.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys, random
import cipher ## Designed GUI

LETTERS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

class CipherDesign(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, cipher.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CipherDesign, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.BGenerate.clicked.connect(self.generatekey) # Generate Button

    def generatekey():
        key = list(LETTERS)
        random.shuffle(key)
        return ''.join(key)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = CipherDesign()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean "crashes" - that sounds worrying.  But anyway the slot to which you connect the clicked signal should not return a value.  That doesn't really make sense.  Change it to just print out the key (for debugging) and see if that bit is working.

Comment: By crash I mean when I press the button it gives me a message "Pythonw.exe has stopped working". Here is the GUI design - http://imgur.com/Xbj0G0v. I want to press the Generate Key button which will display the key generated in the EditLine box; it does generate a key but I do not no how to make it display in the box.

Comment: You should be using `setText` not `return`. What happens when you do that? Add some debugging print statements to your `generateKey` function so you can find where it goes wrong. Also, your `generateKey` function should have `self` as its first parameter.

Comment: Yes! That worked thank you very much. The crashing must have been because I did not have self as the parameter. How come you need self in there is that to ensure it is part of the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your `generateKey` method is missing the self argument and then inappropriately returning the key value rather than assigning it with `setText`.

In normal Python omitting the self parameter would just give a "number of arguments" error when you call `self.generateKey()`.  But here it is being called by PyQT which is (somewhat unexpectedly) causing a crash.

In Python, a call to a method on an object (like `self.generateKey()`) is translated into a call like this `generateKey(self)`.  `self` here is just an arbitrary name (self is used by convention).  This is the mechanism by which the method is associated to the object on which it is called.  Then, in the body of the method, the name `self` is in scope and is bound to the object instance, as you need it to be to use it in Python.

So you should have something like:

```
def generatekey(self):
    key = list(LETTERS)
    random.shuffle(key)
    self.TextBoxObject.setText(''.join(key))
```